# Using PyScripter with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7, pyscripter, python-3

Can someone please let me know how I can set the **PyScripter 2.5.3.0 x64** works with Python 2.7.3 which comes with ArcGIS
what I did was:

1. I installed the ArcGIS 10.2
2. I installed PyScripter 2.5.3.0 x64 which forced my to install Python 3.3
3. I installed Python 3

Now I can't use the PyScripter for ArcGIS Python. I already add the ArcPy in to PyScripter IDE Options--> Special package as: os, wx, SciPy, **ArcPy** but still not working.

I also check the "desktop10.2.pth" at c:\python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages which looks like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts
```

Can you please let me know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: you had to use 32bit version even if you are running x64 machine

Comment: That is true, use http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/downloads/detail?name=PyScripter-v2.5.3-Setup.exe. Another thing is that you want to use Python 2.7 which is installed with ArcGIS instead of Python 3.3 which is not supported for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make sure you have the 32 bit PyScripter installed, not the 64 bit.  Then in Tools -> Python Path make sure you have PyScripter pointing to the following paths:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\DLLs
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
```

Comment: For me it didn't work: I pasted all those paths one by one in PyScripter but as soon as I apply the changes and go back to code, it can't find arcpy module. I go back to the Python Path and the changes I made before are simply not there. PyScripter is not keeping any of my additions. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, instead of "hardcoding" into the system's environment (as below, can't comment there...), you could use a batch file instead:

```
@echo off
set PYSC_DIR=%~dp0
set ARC_VER="ArcGIS10.2"
set ARC_DIR="E:\Esri\Desktop10.2\"
set PYTHONPATH="%PYSC_DIR%\Lib\rpyc.zip";C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip;C:\Python27\%ARC_VER%\DLLs;C:\Python27\%ARC_VER%\lib;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Python27\%ARC_VER%\lib\plat-win;C:\Python27\%ARC_VER%\lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\%ARC_VER%;C:\Python27\%ARC_VER%\lib\site-packages;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%ARC_DIR%\bin;%ARC_DIR%\arcpy;%ARC_DIR%\ArcToolbox\Scripts;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Python27\%ARC_VER%\lib\site-packages\win32;C:\Python27\%ARC_VER%\lib\site-packages\win32\lib;C:\Python27\%ARC_VER%\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH:"=%
start "PyScripter" %PYSC_DIR%\PyScripter.exe --python27
```

I used this with success and i'll be able to change quickly for future versions of ArcGIS or use (my portable version of PyScripter) with different computers!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to have an installation of both PyScripter versions (x64, x86). When I am intended to use arcpy I run the x86 PyScripter with the paths as mentioned above. When I want to use another Python version (3.x) I utilize the x64 version.

Hope that the tip helps.

Answer (score -1):

FOR WINDOWS 7
Right click on My computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > click on “Environment Variables” button >
If there is not a PYTHONPATH variable > New > and name it “PYTHONPATH” and values are added with “;” to include as many items as you want.

C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip;C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\DLLs;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\plat-win;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy;C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\win32;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\win32\lib;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin;

IMPORTANT
don't forget to go to Tools > Options > IDE Option and then type “arcpy” into “Special packages".